# How to disable playback speed option from the player view of ExoPlayer?

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I’m building an application to stream `HLS` Video on demand content. I’m planning to use ExoPlayer in the app. Also, need to to disable the playback speed option, fast-forward option from the player view. Where exactly code can be changed?

How this can be done? Can you help us with the code changes need to be done?

`MainActivity.kt`

```kotlin
package com.halil.ozel.exoplayerdemo

import android.app.Activity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayer
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.MediaItem
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.HlsMediaSource
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource
import com.halil.ozel.exoplayerdemo.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : Activity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private var exoPlayer: ExoPlayer? = null
    private var playbackPosition = 0L
    private var playWhenReady = true

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)
        preparePlayer()
    }

    private fun preparePlayer() {
        exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(this).build()
        exoPlayer?.playWhenReady = true
        binding.playerView.player = exoPlayer
        val defaultHttpDataSourceFactory = DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory()
        val mediaItem =
            MediaItem.fromUri(URL)
        val mediaSource =
            HlsMediaSource.Factory(defaultHttpDataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(mediaItem)
        exoPlayer?.setMediaSource(mediaSource)
        exoPlayer?.seekTo(playbackPosition)
        exoPlayer?.playWhenReady = playWhenReady
        exoPlayer?.prepare()
    }

    private fun releasePlayer() {
        exoPlayer?.let { player ->
            playbackPosition = player.currentPosition
            playWhenReady = player.playWhenReady
            player.release()
            exoPlayer = null
        }
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        releasePlayer()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        releasePlayer()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        releasePlayer()
    }

    companion object {
        const val URL =
            "some_HLS_URL.m3u8"
    }
}
```

`activity_main.xml`

```kotlin
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:argType="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/flRoot"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:keepScreenOn="true">
    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.StyledPlayerView
        android:id="@+id/playerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        argType:fastforward_increment="0"
        argType:resize_mode="fixed_height"
        argType:rewind_increment="15000"
        argType:show_buffering="when_playing"
        argType:show_fastforward_button="false"
        argType:show_next_button="false"
        argType:show_previous_button="false"
        argType:show_rewind_button="false"
        argType:show_subtitle_button="false"
        argType:use_artwork="true"
        argType:use_controller="true"
        argType:use_sensor_rotation="true">
</com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.StyledPlayerView>

    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply hide the icon. If you look at the implementation of the `StyledPlayerControlView.java`, the settings button have the id `R.id.exo_settings`. Try this to hide the icon:

```
binding.playerView.findViewById<View>(R.id.exo_settings).isVisible = false
```

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the steps below your problem will be solved:

**Step-1** : You need to customize ExoPlayer view. Create a new layout file. `exo_player_custom_view`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <View
        android:id="@id/exo_controls_background"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/exo_black_opacity_60" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@id/exo_bottom_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/exo_styled_bottom_bar_height"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/exo_styled_bottom_bar_margin_top"
        android:background="@color/exo_bottom_bar_background"
        android:layoutDirection="ltr">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@id/exo_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start"
            android:layoutDirection="ltr"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/exo_styled_bottom_bar_time_padding"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/exo_styled_bottom_bar_time_padding"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/exo_styled_bottom_bar_time_padding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/exo_styled_bottom_bar_time_padding">

            <TextView
                android:id="@id/exo_position"
                style="@style/ExoStyledControls.TimeText.Position" />

            <TextView style="@style/ExoStyledControls.TimeText.Separator" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@id/exo_duration"
                style="@style/ExoStyledControls.TimeText.Duration" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@id/exo_extra_controls_scroll_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|end"
            android:visibility="invisible">

        </HorizontalScrollView>

    </FrameLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@id/exo_progress_placeholder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/exo_styled_progress_layout_height"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/exo_styled_progress_margin_bottom" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@id/exo_center_controls"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="@dimen/exo_styled_controls_padding">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@id/exo_play_pause"
            style="@style/ExoStyledControls.Button.Center.PlayPause" />
    </LinearLayout>

</merge>
```

**Step-2** : Add the customized file to the relevant place in the xml file.

you have to give this value correctly: `app:controller_layout_id="@layout/exo_player_custom_view"`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:argType="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/flRoot"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:keepScreenOn="true">

    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.StyledPlayerView
        android:id="@+id/playerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:controller_layout_id="@layout/exo_player_custom_view"
        argType:resize_mode="fixed_width"
        argType:show_buffering="when_playing" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi Halil Ozel, thank you for the response. I will surely follow the steps as you have mentioned and let you know about the result.